# There is no ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I \cong F_3$ (Fermat's sum of squares)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

$\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{a + bi : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ are the Gaussian integers. I want to show that there is no ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ is a field of size $3$ (i.e, is $\mathbb{F}_3$).

Here's my approach:

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ is a field, this would make $I$ a prime/maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Moreover, in the reduction $\mathbb{Z}[i] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[i]/I = F_3$, since $1 \mapsto 1$, we would use homomorphism properties to see that $3 \mapsto 0$ which is just a complicated way of saying that $3 \in I$.

Now $(3) \subseteq I$. But we know that through Fermat's sum of squares theorem, since $3 \equiv 3$ mod $4$, we know that $3$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and thus maximal as well. This would mean that $I = (3)$.

Now, we obtain a contradiction in that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3)$ has size $9$, not $3$ (i.e, all elements of the form $a + bi$ were $a, b \leq 3$).

This concludes the proof.

Does this look correct? Is there another way to do it without wielding heavy results like Fermat's sum of squares?

Comment: This is ok. Perhaps for the  sake of completeness, when you make a statement (say, "we know that $3$ is prime"), include a reference ("Theorem ...").

Comment: @markevs They did. They said "we know that through Fermat's sum of squares theorem".

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked whether there are other solutions:

If there existed a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{F}_3$, then the image of $i$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$ would be a square root of $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$, which is clearly not possible.

In particular, there is no ideal $I\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I \cong \mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: +1, that's much simpler and clear!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine.

Alternatively, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID and so $I=\langle a+bi \rangle$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I \cong \mathbb F_3$ implies $a^2+b^2=3$, a contradiction.